# Scrapy custom settings

Tags: python, scrapy

Using `scrapy`, I have in one of my spiders:

```
class IndexSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "indices"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(IndexSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # set custom settings
        custom_settings = {
            'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 2,
            'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
                'freedom.pipelines.IndexPipeline': 300
            }
        }
```

However, when I later try to access the settings via

```
    print(dict(self.settings.get('ITEM_PIPELINES')))
```

they are empty. Background is that I want to control the settings (and possible pipelines) on a per-spider basis.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what if we set it before invoking the parent constructor?
So call super().__init__() after setting that var

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`custom_settings`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.custom_settings) is supposed to be a class attribute:

```
class IndexSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "indices"

    # set custom settings
    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 2,
        'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
            'freedom.pipelines.IndexPipeline': 300
        }
    }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(IndexSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was it!